# During inheritance of ArrayAccess in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem running `composer update` in my Laravel project.

**Error**

> During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return
> type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExi   sts($key) should
> either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset):
> bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWill   Change] attribute should be used to
> temporarily suppress the notice in
> C:\tameenistore\tameenistore\vendor\laravel\
> framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php:1349   Stack trace:
> #0 C:\tameenistore\tameenistore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php(11):
> Illuminate\Foun   dation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8192,
> 'Return type of ...', 'C:\tameenistore...', 1349)   #1
> C:\tameenistore\tameenistore\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(571):
> include('C:\tameenistore...')   #2
> C:\tameenistore\tameenistore\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(428):
> Composer\Autoload\includeFile('C:\tameenisto   re...')   #3
> C:\tameenistore\tameenistore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php(110):
> Composer\Autoload   \ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\Supp...')
> #4 C:\tameenistore\tameenistore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(130):
> collec   t(Array)   #5
> C:\tameenistore\tameenistore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(106):
> Illumi   nate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()   #6
> C:\tameenistore\tameenistore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(89):
> Illumin   ate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManifest()   #7
> C:\tameenistore\tameenistore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(78):
> Illumin   ate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config('aliases')   #8
> C:\tameenistore\tameenistore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades.php(26
> ): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()   #9
> C:\tameenistore\tameenistore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(230):
> Illuminate
> \Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
> #10 C:\tameenistore\tameenistore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(310):
> Illumi   nate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)   #11
> C:\tameenistore\tameenistore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(127):
> Illumi   nate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()   #12
> C:\tameenistore\tameenistore\artisan(37):
> Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component
> \Console\Input\ArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))   #13 {main}

Comment: Probably isssue with mismatch versions!! Install relevant PHP version to match the Laravel's version.

Comment: I tried to do this too but it didn't work

Comment: This problem is down to having the wrong PHP version.  Not much else to advise.

Comment: If you are sure you have the right version, make sure you run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan view:clear`